# SQL Server datetime LIKE select?

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

in MySQL

```
select * from record where register_date like '2009-10-10%'
```

What is the syntax in SQL Server?

Comment: What are you actually wanting to check? That a given datetime has a given date part? Or something else?

Comment: For a healthy discussion on this (including why it's bad to treat `DATETIME` values like strings, and why it can be bad to use `BETWEEN` or `>= AND <=`), see [this blog by Aaron Bertrand](http://is.gd/4EgDF).

Comment: Your question has at least `5` votes for the [tag:like-operator] tag. Could I kindly request that you suggest [tag:sql-like] as a [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/like-operator/synonyms)?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You could use the DATEPART() function

```
SELECT * FROM record 
WHERE  (DATEPART(yy, register_date) = 2009
AND    DATEPART(mm, register_date) = 10
AND    DATEPART(dd, register_date) = 10)
```

I find this way easy to read, as it ignores the time component, and you don't have to use the next day's date to restrict your selection. You can go to greater or lesser granularity by adding extra clauses, using the appropriate DatePart code, e.g.

```
AND    DATEPART(hh, register_date) = 12)
```

to get records made between 12 and 1.

Consult the [MSDN DATEPART docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms174420.aspx) for the full list of valid arguments.

Comment: If there's an index on register_date, this will completely ignore the index and performance will suffer. Probably quite badly.

Comment: Ok, but it does avoid the problem of using the string equivalent of the day after the date in question, which is being suggested in a few of the answers here. Tricky where the date in question is the end of the month, or year.

Answer (score 74):

There's no direct support for LIKE operator against DATETIME variables, but you can always cast the DATETIME to a VARCHAR:

```
SELECT (list of fields) FROM YourTable
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), register_date, 126) LIKE '2009-10-10%'
```

Check the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx) for a complete list of available "styles" in the CONVERT function.

Marc

Comment: agreed - but the OP requested a way to handle datetime with LIKE.... But I agree - datetimes should preferably be handled with ranges like >= and <= or BETWEEN - much better approach

Comment: Thank you everyone. Sorry I'm just a newbie for SQL.

Comment: Be aware, the MSSQL 2012 (I guess older versions too) will convert datetime to varchar as '2014-01-06T16:18:00.045', so keep this in mind if you try to match for hour/minute too.

Comment: The only issue I had with the above sql select is this: 
   ```WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), register_date, 25) LIKE '2009-10-10%'```

Comment: I prefer this method better because I can get monthly and yearly records returned also depending on style of the date variable determines the code 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

'''WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), register_date, 25) LIKE '2009-10%'''' will give me records for October of 2009

Answer (score 10):

If you do that, you are forcing it to do a string conversion. It would be better to build a start/end date range, and use:

```
declare @start datetime, @end datetime
select @start = '2009-10-10', @end = '2009-11-10'
select * from record where register_date >= @start
           and register_date < @end
```

This will allow it to use the index (if there is one on `register_date`), rather than a table scan.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I'm just a newbie for SQL.

Answer (score 9):

You can use CONVERT to get the date in text form.  If you convert it to a varchar(10), you can use = instead of like:

```
select *
from record
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),register_date,120) = '2009-10-10'
```

Or you can use an upper and lower boundary date, with the added advantage that it could make use of an index:

```
select *
from record
where '2009-10-10' <= register_date
and register_date < '2009-10-11'
```

Comment: I think there is typo in where clause, it should be *"where '2009-10-10' >= register_date"*

Comment: @mr_eclair: don't think so, that would include every date before Oct 11th

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, It is not possible to compare datetime towards varchar using 'LIKE'
But the desired output is possible in another way.

```
    select * from record where datediff(dd,[record].[register_date],'2009-10-10')=0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use convert to make the date searchable using LIKE. For example,

```
select convert(VARCHAR(40),create_date,121) , * from sys.objects where     convert(VARCHAR(40),create_date,121) LIKE '%17:34%'
```

Answer (score 4):

**Try this**

```
SELECT top 10 * from record WHERE IsActive = 1 
       and CONVERT(VARCHAR, register_date, 120) LIKE '2020-01%'
```

Answer (score 3):

I am a little late to this thread but in fact there is direct support for the like operator in MS SQL server.

As documented in LIKE help if the datatype is not a string it is attempted to convert it to a string. And as documented in cast\convert documentation:

> default datetime conversion to string is type 0 (,100) which is mon dd
>   yyyy hh:miAM (or PM).

If you have a date like this in the DB:

```
2015-06-01 11:52:59.057
```

and you do queries like this:

```
select * from wws_invoice where invdate like 'Jun%'
select * from wws_invoice where invdate like 'Jun 1%'
select * from wws_invoice where invdate like 'Jun 1 %'
select * from wws_invoice where invdate like 'Jun 1 2015:%'
select * from wws_invoice where invdate like 'Jun ? 2015%'
...
select * from wws_invoice where invdate like 'Jun 1 2015 11:52AM'
```

you get that row.

However, this date format suggests that it is a **DateTime2**, then documentation says:

> 21 or 121 -- ODBC canonical (with milliseconds) default for time,
>   date, datetime2, and datetimeoffset. -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)

That makes it easier and you can use:

```
select * from wws_invoice where invdate like '2015-06-01%'
```

and get the invoice record. Here is a demo code:

```
DECLARE @myDates TABLE (myDate DATETIME2);
INSERT INTO @myDates (myDate)
VALUES
('2015-06-01 11:52:59.057'),
('2015-06-01 11:52:59.054'),
('2015-06-01 13:52:59.057'),
('2015-06-01 14:52:59.057');

SELECT * FROM @myDates WHERE myDate LIKE '2015-06-01%';
SELECT * FROM @myDates WHERE myDate LIKE '2015-06-01 11%';
SELECT * FROM @myDates WHERE myDate LIKE '2015-06-01 11:52:59%';
SELECT * FROM @myDates WHERE myDate LIKE '2015-06-01 11:52:59.054%';
```

Doing datetime searches in SQL server without any conversion to string has always been problematic. Getting each date part is an overkill (which unlikely would use an index). Probably a better way when you don't use string conversion would be to use range checks. ie:

```
select * from record 
where register_date >= '20091010' and register_date < '20091011';
```

Answer (score 2):

The `LIKE` operator does not work with date parts like month or date but the `DATEPART` operator does.

Command to find out all accounts whose Open Date was on the 1st:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Account 
 WHERE DATEPART(DAY, CAST(OpenDt AS DATE)) = 1`
```

*CASTING `OpenDt` because it's value is in `DATETIME` and not just `DATE`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very flaky coverage of the LIKE operator for dates in SQL Server.  It only works using American date format.  As an example you could try:

```
... WHERE register_date LIKE 'oct 10 2009%'
```

I've tested this in SQL Server 2005 and it works, but you'll really need to try different combinations.  Odd things I have noticed are:

- You only seem to get all or nothing for different sub fields within the date, for instance, if you search for 'apr 2%' you only get anything in the 20th's - it omits 2nd's.
- Using a single underscore '_' to represent a single (wildcard) character does not wholly work, for instance, **`WHERE mydate LIKE 'oct _ 2010%'`** will **not** return all dates *before* the 10th - it returns nothing at all, in fact!
- The format is rigid American: '`mmm dd yyyy hh:mm`'

I have found it difficult to nail down a process for LIKEing seconds, so if anyone wants to take this a bit further, be my guest!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this an old question, but a lot of the answers here don't give a SARGable answer here, nor cover parmetrisation.

First off, you are far better off using `>=` and `<` logic. For the date you want, then that would look like this:

```sql
SELECT {Your Columns}
FROM dbo.record
WHERE register_date >= '20091010'
  AND register_date < '20091011';
```

This'll include every time value on 2009-10-10, including the stroke of midnight on the day, and a nanosecond prior to 2009-10-11.

Often, however, you'll be parametrising your query, so instead what you can do is use `DATEADD` to add a day to the second clause:

```sql
DECLARE @DateParam date = '20091010';

SELECT {Your Columns}
FROM dbo.record
WHERE register_date >= @DateParam
  AND register_date < DATEADD(DAY,1,@DateParam);
```

This maintains SARGability and means that any indexes on `register_date` can  be used.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem that way. Thank you for suggestions for improvements.
Example in C#.

```
string dd, mm, aa, trc, data;
dd = nData.Text.Substring(0, 2);
mm = nData.Text.Substring(3, 2);
aa = nData.Text.Substring(6, 4);
trc = "-";
data = aa + trc + mm + trc + dd;

"Select * From bdPedidos Where Data Like '%" + data + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

CAST((CONVERT(VARCHAR, BPM.UpdatedOn, 3)+'' ''+CONVERT(VARCHAR, BPM.UpdatedOn, 108))AS VARCHAR(100)) LIKE ''%' + @Search + '%''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).