# mysqldump with --where clause is not working

Tags: sql, mysql

```
 mysqldump -t -u root -p  mytestdb mytable --where=datetime LIKE '2014-09%'
```

This is what I am doing and it returns:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "LIKE"
```

I am trying to return all the rows where the column `datetime` is `like 2014-09` meaning "all September rows".

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You may need to use quotes:

```
mysqldump -t -u root -p  mytestdb mytable --where="datetime LIKE '2014-09%'"
```

Comment: The reason here is the shell breaks arguments on spaces by default, so it interprets that as three unrelated arguments. Quotes groups them all together.

Comment: thanks. had to use double quotes then single quote as such mysqldump -t -u root -p  mytestdb mytable --where="datetime LIKE '2014-09%'"

Comment: Can you also add the source of your answer?

Comment: @NikhilWagh what do you mean? I do not remember when I used a shell the first time, and quotes were one of the early gotchas I had to learn about, huh, I don't know, thirty years ago.

Comment: For reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Yeah, it says _"[q]uotes around the condition are mandatory if it contains spaces or other characters that are special to your command interpreter"_. That's a feature of your shell.

Answer (score 5):

Selecting dates using LIKE is not a good idea. I saw this method in one project. This causes huge DBMS load and slow system operation as no index by this table column used.

If you need to select date range use between:

```
where datetime between '2014-09-01' and '2014-09-30 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Index is used as long as you do not use the wildcard first so '2019-09%' will use the index as it does not include the wildcard first but '%2014-09%'  will not

Comment: The conversion to string might prevent using index. Some people also confirm that it is better not using like for date comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629050/sql-server-datetime-like-select

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer but just a notice, when using `mysqldump` it will automatically add `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` to the export file, in case you don't want that add `--skip-add-drop-table` and `--no-create-info` with the command, like:

```
mysqldump -u root-p database_name table_name --skip-add-drop-table --no-create-info > export.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed "" for where clause . datetime column name datetime is not recommended. It is a data type as well.

```
mysqldump -u root -p mytestdb mytable --where="datetime LIKE '2014-09%'
" > mytable.sql;
```

After executing the command a prompt will ask for MySQL password. then check your current folder for generated mystable.sql