# How to filter date values in datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

I can't filter a date value in my datagrid. Here is my code:

```
DataTable dbdataset;
DataView DV = new DataView(dbdataset);
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Data LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
```

I always get this error:

```
Unable to Perform Operation 'Like' on System.DateTime and System.String
```

Please can someone help me?

Comment: See: [SQL Server datetime LIKE select?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629050/sql-server-datetime-like-select

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use the `LIKE` operator on `DateTime` Data Type. Try using the equal operator.

```
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Data = '{0}'", textBox1.Text);
```

But, be careful of what's inside `textBox1.Text`. It must be convertible to a `DateTime` Data Type. Remember also that `DateTime` has a `Time` part also, not just a `Date` part.

Or you may want to try this to filter all rows in a specific day:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Data > '{0}' AND Data < '{1}'", dt.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd"), dt.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously field Data is from type Datetime and you can not perform Like on it. You can use:

```
DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Data = '{0}'", textBox1.Text);
```

Also you have possibility with `=, >=, <=.`

Also please change the field name to Date !

You can try something like that in `LINQ`

```
CultureInfo invC = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

var query= from myRow in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                     where myRow.Field<DateTime>("Date").ToString(invC).Contains("mm/dd/yyyy")
                    select myRow;

// the date should be in format months/days/year -> Example 23 January 2014 is 01/23/2014

DataTable newTable= query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Comment: The RowFilter property accepts expressions listed in the DataColumn.Expression property docs. There is no hint that DATEPART is something recognized by this property parser. Did you try it?

Comment: @Steve I will check it, after your comment.

Comment: Still wrong, now you miss the quotes or the pound around the value, but at this point you have the same answer given from the other guy. Probably you don't miss anything if you delete.

Comment: @Steve yes i'm searching for other way. Probably I will go with LINQ

Answer (score 0):

`DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Data >= '{0}'", textBox1.Text);`
will work if your column is a `datetime` in the database. This will return records at or newer than the specified date. Switch the sign to `<` if you're looking for records older than that date.

Comment: When i use >= i get this error "Unable to Perform Operation '>=' in System.DateTime and System.Int32"

Comment: What is the value of `textBox1.Text`? It needs to be a value that can be parsed to a date.