# SQL filter by date returns 0 results

Tags: sql

The CreatedDateTime is the table I am trying to filter by, using SQL

```
SELECT( * ) COUNT
FROM TABLE
WHERE CreatedDateTime like '2015''-''01''-''29%'
```

Return 0 Records

even though I have two records that have a CreatedDateTime of the following

```
CreatedDateTime
2015-01-29 07:33:25.700
2015-01-29 02:01:54.713
```

However the below works

```
like '%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 0) + '%'
```

What am I doing incorrect here?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: we're talking about mysql? SQL server?

Comment: A datetime is not a string. So hopefully your datetime is not a varchar column, is it?

Comment: Q: What am I doing incorrect here?  A: You're treating a "date" like a "string".  BETTER: `select count(*) from mytable where CreatedDateTime between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-30'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server datetime LIKE select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629050/sql-server-datetime-like-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datetime is not a string, Wildcard `%` is used to look for a pattern in a string value.

to get all the values in particular day you can simply cast it to date and that will ignore the time part and will bring back all the records for that particular date. Something like .....

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE CAST(CreatedDateTime AS DATE) = '20150129'  --<-- use ASNI YYYYMMDD
```

Also always stick to ANSI standards, will protect you against environment specific issues.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's stored as a proper datetime you can strip the time portion and use equivalence, since wildcard matching is for strings:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE CAST(CreatedDateTime AS DATE) = '2015-01-29'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
SELECT( * ) COUNT
FROM TABLE
WHERE  (DATEPART(yy, CreatedDateTime) = 2015
AND    DATEPART(mm, CreatedDateTime) = 01
AND    DATEPART(dd, CreatedDateTime) = 29)
```