# BETWEEN clause in DATEPART function

Tags: sql-server

I want to use BETWEEN clause in this query and don't know how to do this

```
SELECT * FROM record 
WHERE  (DATEPART(yy, register_date) = 2009
AND    DATEPART(mm, register_date) = 10
AND    DATEPART(dd, register_date) = 10)
```

Comment: e.g. `WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, register_date) BETWEEN X AND Y`?

Comment: I have to use both year and month in between clause like register_date BETWEEN '2009-10' and '2009-12' and like clause doesn't work for me

Comment: So like `WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, register_date) = 2009 AND DATEPART(MONTH, register_date) BETWEEN 9 AND 12`? Alternatively, you can skip the datepart altogether and just say `WHERE register_date >= '2009-10-10' AND register_date < '2010-12-11'` or something like that.

Comment: i can not use this because i have to use like clause

Comment: use between of what? two dates? what? your example seems like you don't need between clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server datetime LIKE select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629050/sql-server-datetime-like-select)

Comment: i want record of time period between '2009-10' and '2010-12'

Comment: So you want everything that occurred between October 2009 and December 2010, inclusive? That doesn't seem to need to use `DATEPART` at all - just compute your start and end dates (Usually better to specify an exclusive end date if your records include times as well as dates) and use a simple comparison. If that's not right, please put more effort into your question. [edit] it and include *sample data* and *expected results*. (i.e. have some sample data that *shouldn't* be in the result and make it clear *why* rows are/are not to be included)

Answer (score 0):

This gives the records from 5 hours ago until now

```
SELECT * FROM record
WHERE register_date BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

It appears this might be what you want

```
select * from record
where register_date between '2017-10-1' and '2017-12-31'
```

Do note that if you want all records from the last day you might want to add time or pick the day after as the default time is 0:00