# Like with the %

Tags: sql

I am trying to isolate the records returned to just from today.  I am using the like 'XXX%' but it returns no records at all.  What am i doing wrong here?

```
select CREATE_DATE from TELEGRAM_LOG tl with (nolock)
where tl.TELEGRAM_TYPE = 'ARQ'
and tl.DESCRIPTION like '%tuId=M180613969]'
and tl.TELEGRAM like 'ARQ100180423001%'
and tl.CREATE_DATE like  '2020-08-12%'
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a record that meet all the conditions?

Comment: If you change the last line to "and tl.CREATE_DATE > dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()),0)" does it work?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server datetime LIKE select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629050/sql-server-datetime-like-select)

Answer (score 2):

In my answer, I assume `tl.CREATE_DATE` is a `datetime` (or `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset`) column and not a `date` column.

Your SQL isn't working because **the `LIKE` operator is for text (strings, `varchar`, etc) not dates**.

For dates, use the normal `<=` and `>=` operators. You cannot "pattern match" dates like you can with strings - depending on your RDBMS you'll need to use either the `EXTRACT` function, or the individual `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY` scalar functions to compare date components as numbers.

I recommend just using comparison operators, so change your `LIKE` predicate clause to this instead:

```
(
    tl.CREATE_DATE >= '2020-08-12 00:00:00'
    AND
    tl.CREATE_DATE <  '2020-08-13 00:00:00'
)
```

You don't need the time-of-day portion of the date-literals, but I prefer to put them in because it makes it clear to the reader that we're dealing with `datetime` values, not `date` values.

The above predicate can *also* be expressed as:

```
(
    tl.CREATE_DATE > '2020-08-12'
    AND
    tl.CREATE_DATE < '2020-08-13'
)
```

...but if the reader doesn't already know that `tl.CREATE_DATE` is **not** a `date` value then the semantics of this query are different (which why I'm not a fan of SQL in its present form).

If you do want to "pattern match" dates then you'd use the date-component functions (or `EXTRACT`):

```
(
    YEAR( tl.CREATE_DATE ) = 2020
    AND
    MONTH( tl.CREATE_DATE ) = 8
    AND
    DAY( tl.CREATE_DATE ) = 12
)
```

Another approach is to use the `CAST` or `CONVERT` function to change the `datetime`/`datetime2`/`datetimeoffset` value to a `date` value, as this will **truncate** the time-of-day portion, so comparisons will only use the date component, like so:

```
(
    CONVERT( date, tl.CREATE_DATE ) = '2020-08-12'
)
```

Alternatively to all of the above (and as a variation on my initial recommended answer) you could also do it like this:

```
(
    tl.CREATE_DATE >= '2020-08-12 00:00:00'
    AND
    tl.CREATE_DATE <= '2020-08-12 23:59:59'
)
```

That said, I'm not a fan of this approach because it *potentially* excludes events occurring in the 999ms in-between `2020-08-12 23:59:59.001` and `2020-08-13 23:59:59.999` (inclusive), [as well as leap-seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_seconds).

Answer (score 0):

You can use GETDATE() or current_timestamp.

where convert(varchar(10), t1.CREATE_DATE, 102)
= convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102)

Comment: Applying `convert()` to `create_date` prevents the use of indexes and should thus be avoided. Instead inequality operations should be used like @Dai's answer demonstrates.